# Accordion slideshow with coloured sidebar and vertical text

Tags: html, css, slideshow, horizontal-accordion

I am trying to build a website for a health organisation. I would like to include an accordion image slideshow. This is what I have so far, and it works fine:

http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/

What I would like to be able to do is add a colored sidebar to each image with some text like in the following image:

http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/slideshow_idea.png

Does anyone know how I could do this? Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **`div`** for each image and put it inside your **`li`** tags and put the following CSS code to fix to the right side:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 2em !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1382mL7r/1/) for more.

**Snippet:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: 320px;
}

.accordion ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.accordion ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  /* regular width */
  /*width: 11.111%; /* 100% / 9 */
  */ height: 320px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.accordion ul li div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion ul li div a {
  display: block;
  height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.accordion ul li div a * {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.accordion ul li div a h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-overflow: clip;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  top: 220px;
  left: 20px;
}

.accordion ul li div a p {
  top: 220px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}


/*make images scale as window resizes */

.accordion ul li {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}


/* images */

.accordion ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/arthritis.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/cancer.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/cardiac.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/diabetes.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/fall_prevention.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/physio.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(7) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/pre_natal.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(8) {
  background-image: url("http://www.squaremedia.com.au/demosites/accordion_slider/images/weight_loss.jpg");
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(9) {
  background-image: url("images/work_cover.jpg");
}


/* widths for hovering*/


/* width not showing */

.accordion ul:hover li {
  width: 5%;
}


/* (100 - 60) / 8 */


/* width showing */

.accordion ul:hover li:hover {
  width: 60%;
}


/*darken image when hovering */

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/* mobile view */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .accordion {
    height: auto;
  }
  .accordion ul li,
  .accordion ul li:hover,
  .accordion ul:hover li,
  .accordion ul:hover li:hover {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2em !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.sidebar p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-5%, -75%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help!